# Can the same record be loaded from store without a new request using 2 different ids?

Tags: ember-data

Our app's Rails part returns the same record either using an id or a slug:

`/user/1` or `/user/wojtek`

The Ember part has loaded all users. If I want to load a particular record, e.g `User.find(1)`, the record is returned from the store. But if I wanted to load it using the slug, `User.find('wojtek')` a new request has been made.

Maybe it is not applicable in latest Ember (we hasn't upgraded now), but is it possible for Ember to return the same record no matter what param I send? Does Ember use any internal mappings?